# MongoDB :: Convert SQL to MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can anyone convert SQL Query to mongo query::

```
select customerId
from CustomerInfo
where customerId not in (select customerId
from CustomerInfo
where channel = 'A');
```

Here I want to find customerId's for which channel 'A' does not exist.

Comment: Why not `select customerId FROM CustomerInfo WHERE channel <> 'A'`?

Comment: It will also work with SQL. but I want mongo query.

Comment: Would be `db.CustomerInfo.find({channel: {$ne: "A"}}, {customerId: 1})`

Answer (score 0):

```
var customerIds = db.CustomerInfo.find({channel:'A'}).map(function(like) {  
  return like. customerId;  
}); 


db.CustomerInfo.distinct("customerId",{customerId:{$customerIds}})
```

Comment: Mind to explain your solution?